# Launch Failed: Binary Not Found

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I'm running eclipse on SUSE with gcc compiler installed.

When I create new "Hello World" C++ project, clean and build and run I'm faced with "Launch Failed: Binary Not Found".

I try to set a run configuration only to find no binary has been created, no binary folder has been created in project.

Only message from build is :

`**** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld ****
(Cannot run program "make": Unkown reason)`

Binary Parser is set to Elf.

Tried everything on SO with no success.  Only thing I can think of is binary file is being created elsewhere....but no idea where it could be.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Clearly you don't seem to have make installed. Did you check it is?

Comment: I don't understand?  Surely by building the executable is created?  Is this what you mean?

Comment: The error message says the command `make` is not found. Do you have it installed?

Comment: It doesn't say make is not found. It says make cannot be run. This is possibly because make cannot be found, but the error message is pretty explicit that it doesn't know why make won't run. This question cannot be answered without more info. First: open up a console and type `make`. Does make run? If not check if it's installed with `zypper in make`. This will install make if it is missing. After that rerun `make`. If make runs, try to build with Eclipse again .

Comment: Make indeed was not installed, however I uninstalled gcc and reinstalled which seems to be causing issues now compiling, so reinstalling SUES... perhaps you could create an answer detailing what you've suggested.

Comment: Hold off on reinstalling. First try `zypper install -t pattern devel_C_C++`. They may have changed the pattern name and currently I can't check. This will probably give you more than you want, but should get you back up and running.

Comment: OK it was too late.  I reinstalled.  Ran `zypper in gcc` and `zypper in make`.  g++ error still, so ran `zypper in gcc-c++` and hey presto, working.  Thanks for your help @user4581301

Comment: Recommend taking a browse through the C/C++ development pattern. Some other good stuff in there. If they didn't come with GCC, make sure you install GDB and Valgrind. They can make your life so much easier it's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before due to incorrect installation of C++ compiler
use this command in the terminal

> zypper in gcc

and then try again , I actually had this so I Finally Switched to Visual Studio community 2015 it works fine for me

I hope this helps you

adding a link below 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/installing-gcc-on-suse-enterprise-11-a-903014/

Comment: apt-get is debian. SUSE uses zypper. For OP the command will be something like **zypper in gcc**

Comment: `apt-get install gcc` is what I used, is this incorrect?

Comment: When I run `gcc --version` I get `gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5`

Comment: When I run `zypper in gcc` I get `gcc is already installed`.  Must I first uninstall me previous version?

Comment: Nope Lemme see where make is. Back in a few minutes.

Comment: Looks like **zypper in make** should do it. I wanted to confirm, but it looks like I have't fired up the SUSE VM for a while and package kit is busy updating.

Comment: Just to clarify, `zypper in make` is an alternative to `apt-get install gcc` ?  Or should I run both `zypper in gcc` then `zypper in make`?

Comment: You already have GCC installed. Shouldn't need to install it again. `zypper in make` will attempt to install make if it's not already installed, but first open a console and type `make`. If make runs, `make` is installed and the problem is elsewhere. apt-get and zypper are both package managers. Their job is to make sure programs install correctly with all of their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the g++(gcc) compiler

→if you're using arch linux:

```
    sudo pacman -S gcc
```

→if you're using Debian based distributions (like Ubuntu, Mint...)

```
    sudo apt-get install gcc
```

or

```
    sudo aptitude install gcc
```

→if you're using OpenSUSE

```
    sudo zypper install gcc
```

I forget how to install on fedora(22+)/RedHat ...

→From source [Gcc Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC)

After installing, create a "helloworld.cpp" file, then manually compile it, for test, open a terminal on the same directory of this file, then type:

```
    g++ helloworld.cpp -o executable
```

And run it:

```
    ./executable
```

If compiling manually works, and eclipse compiling don't, try to install Make (use "make" instead of "gcc" on commands)

*The helloworld.cpp file, can have the following code:*

```
#include<iostream>

 int main()
 {
    std::cout<<"Hello World!"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: After uninstalling gcc, reinstalling it via zypper then running `zypper in make` I get following error when trying to run hello world - `/bin/sh: g++: command not found`

Comment: I'm so accustomed to "make" on the dependencies, that I forgot it '-', I've edited

Comment: if g++ is not found, is a problem with gcc install, try **zypper in gcc**   (if you uninstalled gcc, probably g++ will not work, so you need install it again)